# what does WindowSize option tell us in vl_phow function?

Tags: matlab

what does WindowSize option tell us in vl_phow function?

The mathworks documentation says it gives size of gaussian window in units of spatial bins but thats not very clear to me how

http://www.vlfeat.org/mdoc/vl_phow.html

Comment: There appears to be a nice plot showing you what the bin size does [here](http://sun360.csail.mit.edu/jxiao/SFMedu/SFMedu/lib/vlfeat/doc/overview/dsift.html), but this all looks a bit like Greek to me so I can't tell if this is really useful or not.

Answer (score 1):

Gaussian function extends to infinity and it must be truncated at some point. Window is the area inside those borders. I think the term "window" is pretty intuitive.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function